# How to handle independent, long running useEffect operations?

Tags: react-hooks

Imagine you've built a React form using React Hooks and the Context API.  When the user presses `Submit` you need to run validation, which consists of checking whether various e-mail addresses already exist, various company names already exist, and perhaps some other async checks need to be made too.

Each of these will be executed independently and you have no guarantee that any specific one of them will be the last to finish.

When you start the validation, you set an `isProcessing` flag to `true`.  When all of the aforementioned checks are complete, you will set `isProcessing` to `false`.

Given that one async call knows nothing about the other async calls, what's a good pattern to manage this situation?  Simply put, how do you know when ALL of the async calls are done so that `isProcessing` can be set to `false` and a `POST` request can be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track,
But generally if all of it are async you should probably use

`Promise.all()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Then you can use a single await for all of your async process. 
Turn on the `isProcessing` then false it after the Promise.all finishes running all of your async validations.

But efficiently wise, I think its better to setup your validation in one single async functions, handling them differently is inefficient and has many calls, though there are special cases in which you depend in third party apis.

Your code should probably something along these

```
useEffect(()=>{
   async function validateFields(){
     // setState isProcessing true
     const asyncValidation1 = promiseFunction();
     const asyncValidation2 = promiseFunction();
     const result = await Promise.all(asyncValidation1 , asyncValidation2);
     // Handle the result
     // setState isProcessing false

   }
    validateFields();

},[])
```

Notice that I wrapped the validation function into a async function. This is because declaring async useEffect is bad practice.

Comment: Interesting.  Thank you!  In fact, today I created a `getAll` wrapper for the existing `axios.get` function.  So indeed, one of the aforementioned async calls going out is definitely using the axios equivalent of `Promise.all`.  I'll now have to think about refactoring the other async calls to all come under one central "umbrella".